# Given a matrix of type `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` how to determine index and value of maximum of each row?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, max, sparse-matrix

Given a sparse matrix`R` of type `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` of shape `1.000.000 x 70.000` I figured out that

```
row_maximum = max(R.getrow(i).data)
```

will give me the maximum value of the i-th row.

**What I need now is the index corresponding to the value `row_maximum`.**

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Thanks for any advice in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getrow(i)` returns a 1 x n CSR matrix, which has an `indices` attribute that gives the row indices of the corresponding values in the `data` attribute.  (We know the shape is 1 x n, so we don't have to deal with the `indptr` attribute.)  So this will work:

```
row = R.getrow(i)
max_index = row.indices[row.data.argmax()] if row.nnz else 0
```

We have to deal with the case where `row.nnz` is 0 separately, because `row.data.argmax()` will raise an exception if `row.data` is an empty array.

Answer (score -1):

use [`numpy.argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) (or `scipy.argmax` which is the same thing)

```
index_of_maximum = scipy.argmax(R.getrow(i).data)
```