# Is there a function analogous to numpy's argpartition in scipy sparse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, scipy

I am attempting to partition a matrix using [`np.argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html).

This works fine for `numpy` matrices but not for `scipy` compressed `csr` matrix.

I am attempting to partition it in axis 1 but since a `scipy` `csr` matrix becomes a vector I am facing issues. Is there an analogous function to `np.argpartition` in `scipy`?

Comment: Do you want to consider only nonzeros or everything?

Comment: There isn't even a `sort` or `argsort` for sparse matrices.  Simply giving a sparse matrix to a numpy function rarely works.   It might help if you gave a small example what you do with the dense array.  Make sure it's sparse and you are clear about how the mix of zeros and nonzeros are handle.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Everything

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30742572/argmax-of-each-row-or-column-in-scipy-sparse-matrix - question about rowwise argmax for sparse.  I have vague memories of questions about finding the top N values per row, but can't find them.

Comment: _Everything_. That's tricky, what format would you want the result in for starters?